# How do I call an action from within its controller such that its filters are also called implicitly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, actioncontroller

I have a controller:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :action1, only: [:create]
    before_action :action2, only: [:create]
    after_action  :action3, only: [:create]

    def create
        # Create one Thing
    end

    def bulkCreate
        thingsCollection.each do |thing|

            # Ideally, I want to call create here such that 
            # all of its filters are called too, without explicit code

            # The BAD Workaround I'm using right now:
            action1
            action2
            create
            action3
        end
    end
end
```

I want to call create from bulkCreate, but I also want to execute all of the filters that create has (action1, action2, action3), without explicitly calling them in order.

I read that I should use redirect_to, but that would cause additional **visible** requests, which I want to avoid.

Any ideas?

Akshay

Comment: Can you post your actual code, including all of the actions

Comment: The actual code uses concerns and a lot of things that are not related to the core problem. 
I'm not sure if copy-pasting the actual code will be more useful. I can clarify any questions you might have about it though.

Comment: @AkshayRao it's interesting question by itself (and I upvote it for this reason), but using this approach is not a good idea at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not recommended approach. If you have some common behavior, better create a new method and call if from both `:create` and `:bulk_create`.

Still if you want to invoke callbacks from method, use `run_callbacks` method.

You can invoke filter actions using:

```
# you should redefine name before callbacks can be invoked
original_action_name = self.action_name
self.action_name = 'test'

# running 'controller#test' method within this block
# which invokes all registered callbacks
run_callbacks :process_action do
  self.test
end

# restore action name
self.action_name = original_action_name
```